# Is there a date for TAGs V2 in Box.NET APIs

Tags: box-api

Is there any date for finishing the Tags APIs V2 in Box.NET? I need to plan this, so I need a date.

I want to change the authentication from V1 to V2 and don't want to break the TAGS whish is the remaining part to migrate in my application.

Thanks

Comment: v2 of tags is in design, with no hard date.  It probably makes sense for us to chat about what you are using Tags for in your application.  I'd like to make sure we cover your use case with the V2 of tags.  Please reach out to me at peter at box

Comment: We are using tags to define the state for documents, like reviewed, draft, paid, pending and so on to be used in search.

So adding, editing and deleting tags is important, also export tags and the number of tags on each file when you get the files in a folder and the tags by file are required APIs

Comment: We are planning on covering your tags use cases.  We're just starting the implementation, so be patient for a few weeks.

Comment: In the roadmap page:
November 22, 2013
V2 Tags – We’ll be adding support for an equivalent of the tagging capabilities in our webapp.

But it is not there yet in the docs!

Comment: Docs should go up in the next 24 hours.  Last bits of QA are happening now

Comment: It's now Jul '14, and there still isn't anything in the Box v2 API for tags.  Can I get an update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tags are added to the documentation under the file object:

https://developers.box.com/docs/#files-file-object

Just wanted to let everybody that this question is answered